# Why does least squares refuse to overfit my data?

Tags: regression, least-squares

I'm generating a toy data with adding sin noise (tried random noise as well). According to theory, if the degree of my polynomial basis is large enough, I should be able to model the wiggles of sin wave. However, I not getting a good fit for my data. Here are the two observations

1. When I try solving this using the normal equations, I get a really bad solution with degree anything larger than 10.

[image]

2. When I use the numpy function np.linalg.lstsq, I get something better but I still not able to get any reasonable fit for my data.

[image]

Here is the code

```
import numpy as np
import random, math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

def polyBasis(data,basisDegree):
    length = data.shape[0]
    result = np.ones((length,1))
    for p in range(1,basisDegree+1):
        nthData = pow(data,p).reshape((length,1))
        result = np.concatenate((result, nthData),1)
    return result

def generateData(data, function, nf):
    result = []
    for datum in data:
        y = 0
        for (i, val) in enumerate(function):
            y = y + val * pow(datum,i)
        #noise = random.random() * nf
        noise = math.sin(datum) * nf
        y = y + noise
        result.append(y)
    return result

X = np.linspace(0,100,1000)
y = generateData(X, [100, 3, 5], 5000) 
#display(x)
#display(y)

Z = polyBasis(X,12)
first_term = np.linalg.inv(np.matmul(Z.T, Z))
second_term = np.matmul(Z.T,y)
w = np.matmul(first_term, second_term)
yhat = np.matmul(Z,w)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.plot(X, y, 'o', figure=fig, label='data')
plt.plot(X, yhat, 'r', figure=fig, label = 'regression')
plt.show()
display(w)

w2,resid,rank,sigma = np.linalg.lstsq(Z,y)
yhat2 = np.matmul(Z,w2)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.plot(X, y, 'o', figure=fig, label='data')
plt.plot(X, yhat2, 'r', figure=fig, label = 'regression')
plt.show()
display(w2)
```

Comment: What do you mean by reasonable fit? Do you want to fit the sinus wave or filter it out?

Comment: Also, is this just a hypothetical toy case or is it some abstract version of your underlying problem? There are nowadays lots of tools to work with autocorrelated data. But then it would help if your question is more specific.

Comment: Short answer: least squares is innocent; you didn't give it scope to do what you seek.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I want to capture the bumps. Given a polynomial of high enough degree, I should be able to capture the bumps but I'm not able to. When I increase the degree, it just goes mad and loses even the basic trend.

Comment: Maybe you are referring to the Taylor series representation of a sine function? Like Peter already told in his answer, this requires a very high order. In practice, if your are doing a least squares regression, your are not going to find the correct polynomial, not even the first few coefficients. Especially in the case of degree larger than ten (which is still far from enough) it will just become a mess. See this wikipedia page  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series for examples of polynomial approximations to sine curves. Even with order>10 only  single bump is captured. You have many.

Answer (score 5):

Your sine wave has 16 cycles, if I counted correctly.  So you would need a polynomial of very high degree to fit it well, if you wanted to capture all the bumps. The second graph does a very good job of capturing your data by removing the bumps, which is what you must want if you are doing it this way.

In a real world problem, you would look at the curve and say "oh! There's something periodic here, I better use a method that deals with that".

Comment: Yes, that's the theory, I should be able to capture it using a polynomial of high degree. But no matter how much I increase the degree, I'm not able to capture the bumps.

Comment: Well, fitting a polynomial with degree 26 or something is going to be problematic. Any noise at all is going to make it a mess. And then, the next cycle will just throw it off again. So, really, you'd need an infinite degree polynomial.